# Caching query in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

```
  Cursor _cursor;
        public Cursor GetCursor()
        {
            return _cursor;     
        }
        public void SetCursor(Cursor cursor)
        {
            this._cursor = cursor;      
        }

    if (GetCursor() == null)
    {
      SetCursor(queueAll());
    }
```

UPDATE:

Is there any mechanism to keep query results in order to reuse them the next time this query occurs?

here is my query:

```
public Cursor queueAll(){
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_CONTENT};
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, columns,
                null, null, null, null, null);

        return cursor;
    }
```

Comment: whats wrong with this question?

Comment: may be you can keep the cursor

Comment: when you make a query in sqlite in android, you often receive a cursor. don't you?

Comment: so whats your question? i am looking a way to cache that cursor.. make sense?

Comment: you can simply keep a reference to it, and requery it when necessary.

Comment: if you happen to know will you show some code? i am not new to sqlite

Answer (score 1):

The return Cursor is the one you want to save.  Just create a Cursor object and save the return value

Comment: i have updated my question, and i did try to store the cursor in prop but when i debug the code, it always show me the _cursor is null

Comment: are you talking about this permission? `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: yes. I'm trying to understand why you getting null.  for some reason you don't get access to your database. 
Do you have an to where the database is?  ie
import uk.ac.my.name.QuestionProvider;

Comment: its not holding into the cursor in my prop and i able to access the table and get the resutlset but when i try to hold it into the prop then i get all the time null, hope this clear

Comment: try making the object which save the result static

Comment: changed to static but still the same